# DevExpress Button is not working on Postback the page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am using devexpress button in my view page when the page is reloading, Button is not working.
But actionlink is working fine with the same condition,

Comment: post some code, how do you try this?

Comment: Why don't you contact DX guys directly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer but i just saw your post and i think the solution to your problem is this:

A DevExpress Button has a property called AutoPostback which is by default set to false. This means that by default the user activity with this button will not be posted back to the server unless you set the AutoPostback property to True.

Let me know if this was a help.

Good Luck